# How do I access the Units="grams" off this xml structure in php

Tags: php, xml, foreach

I have an xml node which is structured like this. How do I add the units (grams in this example) and weight interger into an array?

```
<ItemDimensions>
<Weight Units="grams">9</Weight>
</ItemDimensions>
```

This is the code I've tried so far:

```
if ($result->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->ItemDimensions) {

    foreach ($result->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->ItemDimensions as $key => $value){

        $product['itemDimensions'] = array($key,$value);

    }

}

var_dump($product['itemDimensions']);
```

My var dump gives the following output:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(14) "ItemDimensions" [1]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#27 (1) { ["Weight"]=> string(1) "9" } }
```

However I don't want the string 'weight' as I know it's weight, I want the array to contain the unit type and the amount e.g. grams, 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get to the element `Weight` and then dereference it:

```
$result->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->ItemDimensions->Weight['Units']
```

will give you "grams"

Comment: Can you give an example of how that would be integrated with my code so far?

Comment: It can't be integrated with the code you showed, as that code is not correct.  Don't iterate over it as `key => value`, instead use `->children() as $child`

Comment: I know the code isn't correct, that's why I'm on here, I was just asking for a bit more of an example

Comment: @BenPaton Then you need to provide more context - a little more xml and some explanation of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You've give me the right direction so thanks for that. I just wasn't quite getting it from what you put. I'm just trying to get an array from the xml structure like in this example it would be array('grams',9) rather than what I had which was array('weight',9)

Comment: Well, with the above logic, you'll have something like `$weight = $result->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->ItemDimensions->Weight; $array = [$weight['Units'], $weight]`